# State the midpoint rule

Tags: numerical-methods

State the Midpoint rule for:

$$\int_c^dg(t)dt$$ with $m$ subintervals

Is this how you state it?

$$M_n=\frac{d-c}{m}[g(t_m)]$$

or

$$M_n=\frac{d-c}{m}[g(t_1)+g(t_2)...g(t_m)]$$

Comment: The second is closer, but you will have to specify the $t_i$.

Comment: If you can show me how to do that I'd be grateful, got an exam in 4 hours.

Comment: For $i=0$ to $m$, let $x_i=c+\frac{d-c}{m}i$. Then for $i=1$ to $m$, $t_i=\frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}{2}$. More informally, the $x_i$ are the endpoints of the $m$ equal intervals that $[c,d]$ is divided into, and the $t_i$ are the midpoints of these intervals. Good luck on the exam!

Comment: I am answering now.

Comment: Next time ask questions when you're learning the topic itself, not when the exam looms near! However, I like it that you show your own attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us explore a little bit. I believe that you have an exam soon and I wanted to give you more of an intuistic approach to this problem.

---

Let us take your definite integral of $$\int_c^dg(t)dt.$$

We want to divide the interval $[c,d]$ into $m-$subintervals of equal width such that $$\triangle{t}=\frac{d-c}{m}$$

where we define the subintervals as $[t_0,t_1],[t_1,t_2],\cdots,[t_{m-1},t_m] \ (t_0=c \ \text{and} \ t_m=d)$.

Here is a visual sketch:

[image]

Let $g(t^*_i)$ be the height of the midpoint at midpoint $t^*_i$. Therefore we receive a notion that $$\int_c^dg(t)dt=\triangle{t}g(t^*_1)+\triangle{t}g(t^*_2)+\cdots+\triangle{t}g(t^*_m).$$

By factorization, we get the final result of the midpoint rule to be

$$\int_c^dg(t)dt=\boxed{\triangle{t} \ [g(t^*_1)+g(t^*_2)+\cdots+g(t^*_m)]}=\boxed{\triangle{t} \ [\sum[g(t^*_m)]}.$$

---

I just wanted to give you a bit more insight on this rule about why "it is." All in all, your first equation

$$M_n=\frac{d-c}{m}[g(t_m)]$$

is wrong because you need to account for all heights from $c$ to $d$ in order to receive the correct definite integral. On the other hand, the you equation proceeding the first

$$M_n=\frac{d-c}{m}[g(t_1)+g(t_2)...g(t_m)]$$

is correct only if you refer to the $t_i$ as the midpoints of each subinterval and $g(t_i)$ as the height at each midpoint.

Hope this was helpful!